# Varnish not to cache urls with specific word

Tags: load-balancing, varnish

I am using varnish 4.0.3 as revers proxy caching and load balancer.
I want to avoid varnish caching for links that start with `/api/v1/` or any link that contains `feed` in its link and to serve the request from the backend servers directly.
I have done this:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if ((req.url ~ "^/api/v1/" || req.url ~ "feed") &&
        req.http.host ~ "api.example.com") {
        set req.backend_hint = apis.backend();
    }
```

But based on access log, it serves the first request from Backend and then it serves the new requests from varnish directly! have i done anything wrong? or is there anything else i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```cpp
sub vcl_recv {
    if ((req.url ~ "^/api/v1/" || req.url ~ "feed") 
      && req.http.host == "api.example.com") {
        return (pass);
    }
}
```

The `return (pass)` will switch Varnish to pass mode for the matching requests. In pass mode, Varnish will neither put result to cache, nor deliver from cache (always talks to backend).

A micro-optimisation of a kind is matching `req.http.host` using `==` operator. Regex matching not really needed in this case.